# How to configure sensitivity of outlier detection for time series?

Tags: r

I'm detecting outliers in a periodic time series constructed as so:

```
install.packages("outliers")
time_series_obj = ts(time_series_data, frequency = SOME_VALUE)
fitted_time_series_data <- stl(time_series_obj, "periodic", robust=TRUE)
outliers <- which(fitted_time_series_data$weights<1e-8)
```

The outlier detection is too sensitive for my needs, and I only want to keep the most extreme outliers. (Changing the weight filter has very little effect.) I would like the sensitivity to be configurable (e.g. filter out all outliers with a remainder that has an absolute value greater than k standard deviations or some similar approach).

Comment: Which function above is from `outliers`? What standard deviation do you want to filter on exactly? You didn't provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so it's difficult to know exactly what your are experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

The package `tsoutliers` provides a procedure for the detection of some types of outliers in time series. In this package, the sensitivity can be configured by setting the critical value used in the t-tests.